# Reset the current date in dropdown datepicker of ANTD in react js

Tags: javascript, antd

Problem:
after closing the modal the datepicker of antd not reset If user select the date 2030 and close the modal after reopen the modal in datepicker selected year is 2030

i have read antd datepicker documentation and According to Antd doc if defaultPickerValue is set then it will show current date on reopen modal, but not working as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/status-try-antd-zdpkc9

Comment: did you try value and on change instead

Answer (score 0):

you can force the re-render of a component by modifying the "key" property. Simply generate a key that you will pass through the props to your datepicker. When you close your modal, set a new key, and your component will be re-rendered by React, thus resetting to its initial state. Here's an example based on your sandebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/status-try-antd-forked-5nvws6?file=/demo.js

Answer (score -1):

Change `defaultValue={moment()}` to `defaultValue={[moment()]}`

pass the default value as an array since it's range picker.

Check the props reference for RangePicker here https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#RangePicker

Comment: I have followed the solution you provided but it doesn't work, do you have an example of the correct implementation?